# SQL result showing Vertically instead of Horizontally

Tags: sqlplus

When I do `select table from sql` the result is shown like this:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM SALES
  2  WHERE QUANTITY = '1';

SALES_ID
--------------------
PROMOTION_ID
--------------------
PRODUCT_ID
--------------------
STORE_ID
--------------------
QUANTITY
--------------------
S1
P1
BURGER1
STORE1
1

S2
P1
BURGER2
STORE1
1

S3
P1
BURGER1
STORE2
1
```

But I want it to be shown like this:

```
SALES_ID PROMOTION_ID PRODUCT_ID STORE_ID QUANTITY
----------------------------------------------------------
S1       P1            BURGER1   STORE1   1
```

I've tried the unpivot and pivot thing but still not working.

I've also tried following command:

```
column data_type format a25
set line 20
set pagesize 100/
```

Comment: `SET LINE 20` will make sql*plus put a line break after 20 characters. Try `SET LINE 200` instead, that should fit your result in a single line. (I'm assuming you are using Oracle/sqlplus.)

Comment: set line 200 makes it even worst

Comment: I cant comment the code, but its not better

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to stem from the width of the columns in the database. You seem to have wide columns and short data.

To make it look pretty you need to specify presentation width for all fields that are wider in the database than you want in the presentation.

You can put all those configuration commnds in a file and then invoke it with a single command.

sqlConfig.sql:

```
set line 200
column SALES_ID format a25
column promotion_id format a25
column product_id format a25
```

Running it:

```
start sqlConfig.sql
```

[Tom Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_plus_column_format.htm) has some good formatting tips and I referred to the linked page when writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, what I did was

```
column SALES_ID format a25
column promotion_id format a25
column product_id format a25
column store_id format a25
column quantity format a25
```

Should I do this to all my table or is there a way to do it all at once?

not it shows like this

```
SALES_ID             PROMOTION_ID         PRODUCT_ID           STORE_ID                  QUANTITY
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------- --------------------
S1                   P1                   BURGER1              STORE1                    1
S2                   P1                   BURGER2              STORE1                    1
S3                   P1                   BURGER1              STORE2                    1
```